# Cookies to store previous values Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Hi guys I am developing a servlet that used previously stored values for missing parameters. And if the user first time visits the page and hasnt entered any values shows error for parameter values; My problem is when the values are null it doesnt show error. Secondly my cookies store previous values for once. For example if I entered missing values it will show previously entered values but second time if I do it successively It will show null. here is my code below:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse          response) throws ServletException, IOException {
Cookie cookie1,cookie2,cookie3;
    String getfirst=request.getParameter("first");
    String getlast=request.getParameter("last");
    String getemail=request.getParameter("email");
    cookie1 = new Cookie("firstname", getfirst);
    cookie2 = new Cookie("lastname", getlast);
    cookie3 = new Cookie("email", getemail);
    cookie1.setMaxAge(3600);
    cookie2.setMaxAge(3600);
    cookie3.setMaxAge(3600);
    response.addCookie(cookie1);
    response.addCookie(cookie2);
    response.addCookie(cookie3);
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();



Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if (cookies!=null) {
    Cookie ck;

    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        ck = cookies[i];
        out.println(ck.getName() + " "
                + ck.getValue());
    }}
     else{
        out.println("Unknown value");


}
```

Comment: You either have to keep setting the cookie again on every request, or set a "time to live" for the cookies

Comment: Can you become more specific?

Comment: In your code you always create and set new cookies, regardless if they already existed. So before creating new ones, first check if they already exist, then check if you really need to update the cookie's  value.

Comment: I think thats not the solution my problem